# Use JavaScript Creat Threejs Label Method

Tags: javascript, three.js

JS I know a little bit, I want to use the JS function to provide a label for the Three.js function.

[Go Demo Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qk4O.jpg)

[image]

In this case I want to create a label for each vertex. But, why did it just create one.

update_labels:

```
    function update_labels( vpos ) {


    var pos = get_screen_xy( vpos , camera );


    note.style.display = 'block';

    if ( pos.x >= x_max ) {
        note.style.left = '';
        note.style.right = x_max - pos.x;
    } else {
        note.style.right = '';
        note.style.left = pos.x;
    }

    if ( pos.y == y_max ) {
        note.style.top = '';
        note.style.bottom = y_max - pos.y;
    } else {
        note.style.bottom = '';
        note.style.top = pos.y;
    }

}
```

get_screen_xy:

```
    function get_screen_xy( position, camera ) {
    var pos = position.clone();
    projScreenMat = new THREE.Matrix4();
    projScreenMat.multiplyMatrices( camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse );
    pos.applyProjection( projScreenMat );

    return { x: ( pos.x + 1 ) * window.innerWidth / 2,
        y: ( - pos.y + 1 ) * window.innerHeight / 2 };
}
```

use function:

```
    function getpos1(){
    var notepos1 =objects.geometry.vertices[0];
    update_labels( notepos1 );
}

function getpos2(){
    var notepos2 =objects.geometry.vertices[1];
    update_labels( notepos2 );
}

function getpos3(){
    var notepos1 =objects.geometry.vertices[2];
    update_labels( notepos1 );
}

function getpos4(){
    var notepos2 =objects.geometry.vertices[3];
    update_labels( notepos2 );
}

function getpos5(){
    var notepos1 =objects.geometry.vertices[4];
    update_labels( notepos1 );
}

function getpos6(){
    var notepos2 =objects.geometry.vertices[5];
    update_labels( notepos2 );
}

function getpos7(){
    var notepos1 =objects.geometry.vertices[6];
    update_labels( notepos1 );
}

function getpos8(){
    var notepos2 =objects.geometry.vertices[7];
    update_labels( notepos2 );
}



function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    controls.update();
    render()
}



function render() {

    camera.lookAt( scene.position );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    getpos1();
    getpos2();
    getpos3();
    getpos4();
    getpos5();
    getpos6();
    getpos7();
    getpos8();
}
```

**PLZ help me to fix it, thanks a lot!**

---

**Thanks 2pha:**

I can do it now
[image: Like this]

**But Produced a lot of the same code，Can you reduce some code，I hope to get a perfect code.**

I give full code here:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo: Example of how to implement 2D labels for 3D objects using Three.js</title>
    <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/TrackballControls.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
    var camera, controls, scene, renderer;
    var geometry, material, mesh;

    var x_min = 0;
    var y_min = 0;

    var x_max = window.innerWidth;
    var y_max = window.innerHeight;

    var x_mid = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var y_mid = window.innerHeight / 2;


    var objects = [];

    init();
    animate();

    function init() {


        //CAMERA
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
        camera.position.z = 50;
        camera.position.x = 25;
        camera.position.y = 15;




        controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );

        controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );


        //RENDER

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );



        //SCENE
        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        //LIGHT

        var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xff0000, 2.5, 100 );
        light.position.set( 50, 50, 50 );
        scene.add( light );

        var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 ); // soft white light
        scene.add( light );



        //MESH

        geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 20, 20, 20 );

        sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, 32, 32 );


        material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
                color: 0xFF0000 ,
                side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                specular: 0x222222,
                shading:THREE.NoShading,
                wireframe:true,
            } );

        objects = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        var vector = objects.geometry.vertices[2];

        scene.add( objects );




        objects.position.x = 0;
        objects.position.y = 0;
        objects.position.z = 0;

        note = document.createElement( 'div' );
        note.innerHTML = '0';
        note.style.display = 'none';
        note.style.position = 'absolute';
        note.style.color = 'white';
        note.style.border = '1px';
        note.style.borderColor = 'white';
        note.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
        note.style.borderRadius = '50%';
        note.style.padding = '0.5em';
        note.style.width = '20px';
        note.style.textAlign = 'center';

        note.style.background = 'green';
        note.style.opacity = '0.8'; 

        document.getElementsByTagName( 'body' )[0].appendChild( note );




        note1 = document.createElement( 'div' );
        note1.innerHTML = '1';
        note1.style.display = 'none';
        note1.style.position = 'absolute';
        note1.style.color = 'white';
        note1.style.border = '1px';
        note1.style.borderColor = 'white';
        note1.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
        note1.style.borderRadius = '50%';
        note1.style.padding = '0.5em';
        note1.style.width = '20px';
        note1.style.textAlign = 'center';

        note1.style.background = 'green';
        note1.style.opacity = '0.8';

        document.getElementsByTagName( 'body' )[0].appendChild( note1 );


        note2 = document.createElement( 'div' );
        note2.innerHTML = '2';
        note2.style.display = 'none';
        note2.style.position = 'absolute';
        note2.style.color = 'white';
        note2.style.border = '1px';
        note2.style.borderColor = 'white';
        note2.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
        note2.style.borderRadius = '50%';
        note2.style.padding = '0.5em';
        note2.style.width = '20px';
        note2.style.textAlign = 'center';

        note2.style.background = 'green';
        note2.style.opacity = '0.8';

        document.getElementsByTagName( 'body' )[0].appendChild( note2 );

        note3 = document.createElement( 'div' );
        note3.innerHTML = '3';
        note3.style.display = 'none';
        note3.style.position = 'absolute';
        note3.style.color = 'white';
        note3.style.border = '1px';
        note3.style.borderColor = 'white';
        note3.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
        note3.style.borderRadius = '50%';
        note3.style.padding = '0.5em';
        note3.style.width = '20px';
        note3.style.textAlign = 'center';

        note3.style.background = 'green';
        note3.style.opacity = '0.8';

        document.getElementsByTagName( 'body' )[0].appendChild( note3 );


    }








    function getpos1(){
        var notepos1 =objects.geometry.vertices[0];
        update_labels( notepos1, note );
    }

    function getpos2(){
        var notepos2 =objects.geometry.vertices[1];
        update_labels( notepos2, note1 );
    }

    function getpos3(){
        var notepos3 =objects.geometry.vertices[2];
        update_labels( notepos3, note2 );
    }

    function getpos4(){
        var notepos4 =objects.geometry.vertices[3];
        update_labels( notepos4, note3 );
    }

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        controls.update();
        render()
    }

    function render() {

        camera.lookAt( scene.position );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
        getpos1();
        getpos2();
        getpos3();
        getpos4();

    }



function update_labels( vpos, note ) {


    var pos = get_screen_xy( vpos , camera );


    note.style.display = 'block';

    if ( pos.x >= x_max ) {
        note.style.left = '';
        note.style.right = x_max - pos.x;
    } else {
        note.style.right = '';
        note.style.left = pos.x;
    }

    if ( pos.y == y_max ) {
        note.style.top = '';
        note.style.bottom = y_max - pos.y;
    } else {
        note.style.bottom = '';
        note.style.top = pos.y;
    }

}

    // Get the screen x,y coordinates of the 3D object
    // https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/78#issuecomment-846917
    function get_screen_xy( position, camera ) {
        var pos = position.clone();
        projScreenMat = new THREE.Matrix4();
        projScreenMat.multiplyMatrices( camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse );
        pos.applyProjection( projScreenMat );

        return { x: ( pos.x + 1 ) * window.innerWidth / 2,
            y: ( - pos.y + 1 ) * window.innerHeight / 2 };
    }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you are only referencing the one note variable in the update_labels() so each time the update_labels() function runs, it moves the same label every time.

Show us how you create the notes and we can probably help you more.

Maybe if you send the note you want to change to the update_labels() function.

```
function update_labels( vpos, note ) {


    var pos = get_screen_xy( vpos , camera );


    note.style.display = 'block';

    if ( pos.x >= x_max ) {
        note.style.left = '';
        note.style.right = x_max - pos.x;
    } else {
        note.style.right = '';
        note.style.left = pos.x;
    }

    if ( pos.y == y_max ) {
        note.style.top = '';
        note.style.bottom = y_max - pos.y;
    } else {
        note.style.bottom = '';
        note.style.top = pos.y;
    }

}
```

And call it like:

```
update_labels( notepos1, note1 );
update_labels( notepos2, note2 );
```

etc.

Also, You should probably start accepting answers as I notice you have a few questions, most with answers, but you have not accepted any.